# Can't invoke pop-up of operation?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, operator

I want to make an interface so that I can control my python methods I have already made. So I am trying to make a pop-up of an operation I made (see code below). But I get an error in the last line where I test to call it:

RuntimeError:

> Operator 'MESH_OT_generate_mold' does not have register enabled, incorrect invoke function

```
import bpy

class GENERATEMOLD_OT_template(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Generate Mold"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.generate_mold"
    bl_label = "Generate Mold"

    z_height: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "Z height: ")

    #@classmethod
    #def poll(cls, context):
    #    return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        
        self.z_height = 3
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices = 32, radius = 1, depth = self.z_height)
                
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_popup(self, event)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GENERATEMOLD_OT_template)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GENERATEMOLD_OT_template)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.mesh.generate_mold('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

The name "`MESH_OT_generate_mold`" is not something I called it. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You did call it `MESH_OT_generate_mold`, but indirectly. The `bl_idname` is `mesh.generate_mold` which translates to the expected class name `MESH_OT_generate_mold`. However, your chosen class name doesn't match. The actual error is in the missing `bl_options` though.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I figured it out. I needed this: bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}    But it turned out these pop-up wasn't what I needed :-(